# Why processing.runalg("gdalogr:rasterize"....) is not creating out files when running in the QGIS 2.6.0 console?

Tags: gdal, pyqgis, qgis-processing, rasterization

I want to use the QGIS python scripting functions to turn to rasterize a point vector using many different dimensions.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
import processing

RasterPixelSize = (10.0,20.0,30.0,40.0,50.0,60.0,70.0,80.0,90.0,100.0)

for rps in RasterPixelSize:
    processing.runalg("gdalogr:rasterize","/home/cparr/Documents/Inuvik   /West_Hourglass/spiral.shp","DEPTHCM_AL",None,0,[rps],[rps],0,"/home/cparr/Documents/Inuvik/SpiralToRaster/test.tif")

print "Done"
```

And in the console I get this message:

```
execfile(u'/home/cparr/Documents/Inuvik/QgisScripts/rasterize.py'.encode('UTF-8'))
Error: Wrong parameter value: [10.0]
Error: Wrong parameter value: [20.0]
Error: Wrong parameter value: [30.0]
Error: Wrong parameter value: [40.0]
Error: Wrong parameter value: [50.0]
Error: Wrong parameter value: [60.0]
Error: Wrong parameter value: [70.0]
Error: Wrong parameter value: [80.0]
Error: Wrong parameter value: [90.0]
Error: Wrong parameter value: [100.0]
Done
```

The help for rasterize shows:

```
processing.alghelp("gdalogr:rasterize")
ALGORITHM: Rasterize (vector to raster)
INPUT <parameters>
FIELD <parameters from INPUT>
WRITEOVER <parameters>
DIMENSIONS <parameters>
WIDTH <parameters>
HEIGHT <parameters>
RTYPE <parameters>
OUTPUT <OutputRaster>


DIMENSIONS(Set output raster size (ignored if above option is checked))
0 - Output size in pixels
1 - Output resolution in map units per pixel
RTYPE(Raster type)
0 - Byte
1 - Int16
2 - UInt16
3 - UInt32
4 - Int32
5 - Float32
6 - Float64
7 - CInt16
8 - CInt32
9 - CFloat32
10 - CFloat64
```

And I believe my parameters are correct. Does anyone have experience scripting the QGIS processing tools from the python console?

Comment: Does it work if you use integer values?

Comment: I tried replacing the floats with integers - same result! e.g. "Error wrong parameter value: [20].

Comment: Hmm, what about if you say `[rps,rps]` or `rps,rps`

Comment: @BradHards the code runs using `rps,rps` but does not create any output.tif files. Maybe something is wrong with my output parameter string. I'll try some other output options.

Comment: I have QGIS 2.6.1 installed and when I check the parameters for the rasterize algorithm, I do not have the `WRITEOVER` and `RTYPE` parameters but I am able to run the algorithm using your code (excluding those parameters mentioned). Did you install additional libraries/plugins?

Comment: @Joseph I do have a few additional plugins installed - do you think that might impact how the Rasterize processing tool functions? I'll try upgrading to 2.6.1. or other later version and see how it functions.

Comment: @CharlesParr - It shouldn't. As you have commented in the answer, it could have been the parameters you set. Hopefully the answer helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool works well. I modified slightly the code for producing only 3 raster (10, 20 and 30 Pixel Size) with a point shapefile with 5 features.

```
import processing

RasterPixelSize = (10.0,20.0,30.0)

i=1

for rps in RasterPixelSize:

    processing.runalg("gdalogr:rasterize",\
    "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/point.shp",\
    "id",None,1,rps,rps,6,
    "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/test" + str(i) + ".tif")

    i += 1

print "Done!"
```

The first one with 10 Pixel Size:

[image]

The second one with 20 Pixel Size:

[image]

and finally the third with 30 Pixel Size:

[image]

I used a **RTYPE** of 6 (Float64) whose type was effectively checked in the Layer Properties of each raster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe the problem was with my output string or the **RTYPE** parameter I selected.

Comment: The first problem was to use a list for the **RasterPixelSize**. On the other hand, how many features does the vector point have? What is its projection?

Comment: The vector shapfile has around 12,000 points. Projection is WGS84 UTM Zone 8N.